# Can I write a single List Stream for this?

Tags: java

Say, I have a Config class as below (I have included the class below)

The (parentType, subType) pair can have one of these {(0, 0), (X, 0), (X, Y)}
Where X is > 0, and Y > 0. A value of 0 for, either parenttype or subtype, means it is a common configuration. A non-zero value is a specific configuration. Common configuration is applicable to all types, especially if there is no specific configuration.

If I have a list (List) of Config objects with the following values, values given in this format (category, parenttype, subtype, value):

```
("A", 0, 0, 5), ("A", 2, 0, 6), ("A", 2, 1, 9)
("B", 0, 0, 5), ("B", 2, 0, 6), 
("C", 0, 0, 5), ("C", 4, 0, 13)
("D", 4, 1, 11), ("D", 4, 0, 9)
```

If I am searching for configs for parent type = 2, and sub type = 1, I would like the following list as the result list.
`("A", 2, 1, 9), ("B", 2, 0, 6), ("C", 0, 0, 5)`

We do not get "D" objects because, under "D", we do not have specific parent type 2, and it does not have common parent type 0.

Similarly, If I am searching for configs for parent type = 4, and sub type = 1, I would like the following list as the result list.
`("A", 0, 0, 5), ("B", 0, 0, 5), ("C", 4, 0, 13), ("D", 4, 1, 11)`

For parent type 4, and sub type 1 (just an idea is coded below)
list.stream().filter(oneConf -> (4.equals(oneConfig.getParentType()) && 1.equals(oneConfig.getSubType()))).findFirst().orElse(null)

Above will give only 4 and 1 configuration.
I could have two more
list.stream().filter(condition for 4 and 0)...
list.stream().filter(condition for 0 and 0)...

Given parenttype 4 and subtype 1, can we get the following result list, with Java 8 features, without writing many loops of code.
("A", 0, 0, 5), ("B", 0, 0, 5), ("C", 4, 0, 13), ("D", 4, 1, 11)

```
public class Config {
    String category;
    Integer parentType;
    Integer subType;
    Integer value;
    
    public Config() {}
    public Config(String pCategory, Integer pParentType, Integer pSubType, Integer pValue) {
        category = pCategory;
        parentType = pParentType;
        subType = pSubType;
        value = pValue;
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to match each type (parent/sub) where value matches input or where the value is 0. I also make the guess that you only want one Config from each category.

This might do what you want:

```
private static List<Config> filterConfig(List<Config> list, int parentType, int subType) {
    return new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.parentType == 0 || c.parentType == parentType)
            .filter(c -> c.subType == 0 || c.subType == subType)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    c -> c.category,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (p, q) -> p.parentType != 0 ? (p.subType != 0 ? p : q) : q
            )).values());

}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println("2/1");
filterConfig(list, 2, 1).forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println("4/1");
filterConfig(list, 4, 1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
2/1
Config{category='A', parentType=2, subType=1, value=9}
Config{category='B', parentType=2, subType=0, value=6}
Config{category='C', parentType=0, subType=0, value=5}
4/1
Config{category='A', parentType=0, subType=0, value=5}
Config{category='B', parentType=0, subType=0, value=5}
Config{category='C', parentType=4, subType=0, value=13}
Config{category='D', parentType=4, subType=1, value=11}
```

**Explanation**

The first filter finds any Config matching parentType or where parentType is 0 (and removes any non hits).

The second filter finds any Config matching subType or where subType is 0.

The Collector.toMap() puts the objects in a map with category as the key. This makes sure we find at most 1 Config per category. The value is the Config object itself.

The third parameter to toMap() is a selector which picks one out of two objects when there is a key collision. The lambda I put should first pick whichever one has a non 0 parentType and secondly a non 0 subType. If non was found, pick the second one.

Disclaimer: I have only tested it for your input so that lambda might need tweaking.